# Debug an always pending request IIS MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

How do I debug an always pending request? This morning something strange started to occur, one request (which should download an PDF file) stopped working. When I reproduce the error I can't see anything in the web browser (tried multiple browsers just in case) or any log files on the server.

All the other requests works fine which makes everything seems strange. I have checked at another server with identical code and there it works just fine, also I have tried to do an iisreset without any success. On the hardware side everything seems great (cpu, ram, disk, network).

We use windows server 2012 and IIS 8

Any ideas on where can I start look for errors?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the first line of the method that you suspect is causing the problem. Is your page calling an API controller method over AJAX? Put a breakpoint on the API controller method.

Comment: It is just a regular controller. The problem is that the request doesn't seem to reach the controller (or the application at all) as we do not get any logs anywhere. Also this is on a server in production so it is hard to set a breakpoint

Comment: Then look for patches that were installed on the server recently. If this only started failing today, chances are a patch was installed this morning of during the night that has some incompatibility with your code or your IIS.

Comment: Just looked and the latest patch was installed january 28th

Comment: can you confirm if nothing got logged in the Event log. Also check the request time out, try reducing it.